# How can I map Ctrl-W to close the current editor tab when using IdeaVim + IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I want Ctrl-W to close the current editor tab in IntelliJ IDEA. I use IdeaVim, and somehow that seems to be thwarting my attempts.

Things I've tried that didn't work:

- Adding a "Ctrl+W" shortcut to Settings → Keymap → Main menu → Window → Editor Tabs → Close. This *does* work if I disable IdeaVim.
- Adding a "Ctrl+W" shortcut to Settings → Keymap → Plugins → IdeaVim →  Close current window. This doesn't seem to do anything at all!?
- `:nmap <C-W> <C-F4>` (the default shortcut of Ctrl-F4 does what I want -- I just want Ctrl-W to do it)

I've also tried using the normal vim key of "Ctrl-W c", but this closes *all* editor tabs, not just the current one.

IdeaVim also doesn't seem to know either `:wincmd` or `:tabclose`.

Is there any way to set Ctrl-W as a shortcut for closing the current editor tab while IdeaVim is active (ideally in normal mode, but all modes would be fine too)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm using Android Studio, which is built on IntelliJ, and this works for me:

Go to Settings → Other Settings → Vim Emulation, then change the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut to be handled by IDE.

[image: Screenshot of Vim Emulation settings]

You probably also need to add the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut to Settings → Keymap → Main menu → Window → Editor Tabs → Close. But you said that you have already done it.

Comment: Note that in more recent versions (at least 2019.2), this setting appears to have moved to Settings → *Editor* → Vim Emulation

Answer (score 0):

In *.ideavimrc*
you can Add the following line

```
nmap <C-W> :action CloseEditor<CR>
```

This will allow the ideavim to close the current editor tab